# Get position of element by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, position, margin, absolute

I've seen dozens of scripts that can catch the x and y position of an element/object within the page. But I am always having trouble with catching the x and y when the webpage is using margins at the body, or other elements, absolute/relative elements, such like that.

Is there a solution which provides the exact position, no matter what margins or paddings are used?

Answer (score 12):

I use following code to move div box to follow cursor in this [Web IME site](http://burglish.com)

```
function xy(x) {
    o = document.getElementById(x);
    var l =o.offsetLeft; var t = o.offsetTop;
    while (o=o.offsetParent)
        l += o.offsetLeft;
    o = document.getElementById(x);
    while (o=o.offsetParent)
        t += o.offsetTop;
    return [l,t];
}
```

Its return an array [left,top],

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your code, but when the page have a margin at the body, the position isnt corrent anymore, you got a solution for that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how about adding `document.body.offsetLeft` and `document.body.offsetTop` to the return values?

Comment: This should work fine regardless of body margins. Make sure you're using a Standards Mode doctype though. In Quirks all bets are off.

Comment: Thank you Mark, i will try that one!
@Bobince, i do not have any control over the website where this code will be published, this is part of an interactive advertisement.

Comment: Why do you traverse up the DOM tree twice if you can get both `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` in one loop?

Comment: @DeaDEnD, exactly... use the solution below instead.

Comment: ...In addition to looping twice for no reason...this also creates global ghost variable `o`, would fail in strict mode, and for some reason feels the need to call `document.getElementById` twice on the same id to set it to the same variable only a couple of lines apart... _this answer is downright terrible code, please use Pacerier's answer below._

Answer (score 11):

Getting the exact position is simply a matter of adding the offsetLefts and offsetTops recursively to the [offsetParents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.offsetParent):

```
function getPos(ele){
    var x=0;
    var y=0;
    while(true){
        x += ele.offsetLeft;
        y += ele.offsetTop;
        if(ele.offsetParent === null){
            break;
        }
        ele = ele.offsetParent;
    }
    return [x, y];
}
```

Btw, this solution would probably run twice faster than [the other solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1769630/632951) since we only loop once.

Comment: @YOUs code could be drastically simplified making them roughly the same, whereas his would be more concise.

Answer (score 8):

`offsetParent` and other offset functions are old... use the `getBoundingClientRect`
function... use this:

```
function getAbsPosition(element) {
   var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
   return {x:rect.left,y:rect.top}
}
```

now you can use it like this

```
<div style="margin:50px;padding:50px;" id="myEl">lol</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var coords = getAbsPosition( document.getElementById('myEl') );
    alert( coords.x );alert( coords.y );
</script>
```

Don't worry... no matter how much margin or position or padding the element has, it always works

Comment: This will adjust the numbers as per current scroll. So if you have scrolled 50px down, it will be 50px less.

Comment: Anyone know of a solution that doesn't take into account the user's previous scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some improvements on @Pacerier 's code in my own answer:

```
function getPos(el, rel)
{
    var x=0, y=0;
    do {
        x += el.offsetLeft;
        y += el.offsetTop;
        el = el.offsetParent;
    }
    while (el != rel)
    return {x:x, y:y};
}
```

If is just used as `getPos(myElem)` will return global position. If a second element is included as an argument (i.e. `getPos(myElem, someAncestor)`) that is an ancestor/parent of the first (at least somewhere up the chain) then it will give the position *relative to that ancestor*. If `rel` is not given (i.e. is left `undefined`), then it purposefully uses `!=` instead of `!==` because it should stop when `el` gets to `null` and `rel` is `undefined` as well, so the non-strict equality is purposeful, don't change it. It also returns an object, since that's a bit more readable in usage than an array (and so you can do something like `getPos().x`).

This is derived from Pacerier's solution, so if you're gonna upvote this, consider upvoting his too.