# Getting HTML table row position and showing div next to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've managed to show `<div>` which contains a relevant image to the table row, but I want my `<div>` to appear next to the clicked row like this:

[image]

In this example, when user clicks on second row, `<div>` is shown right next to it. So, how do I get position of clicked row?

I tried
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/dynamically-retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769584/get-position-of-element-by-javascript) solutions, but they both return the table's position instead of row's.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried, not links to the code.  Questions here should be all inclusive and not require research just to figure out what you're asking.

Comment: Did you attempt to use `$.offset` or `$.position`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the index of the row that was clicked? Like "0", or "2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example to get you started using jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/CtWSf/

```
$('td').click(function(e){
    var currentPosition = $(this).offset();
    $('.results').html(currentPosition.top);
});
```

For this markup -

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
</table>
<div class="results"></div>
```