# Angular: get coordinates of table row

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to place a tooltip next to a table row in Angular 1.5, similar to something like this: [Getting HTML table row position and showing div next to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588977/getting-html-table-row-position-and-showing-div-next-to-it) (but this is jQuery)

I'm trying to pass the table row element to a controller function, but seem unable to access the element.

I've tried:

Template snippet:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="s in sessions"
            ng-mouseover="showPopup(this)"
            ...
```

Javascript snippet:

```
        $scope.showPopup = function($event) {
            console.log(angular.element(this)); // [p]
            console.log(angular.element(this).prop('offsetLeft')); // undefined
            console.log($event.target); // undefined
        console.log(angular.element($event.target).prop('offsetLeft')); // undefined
```

How can I get the actual coordinates of the table row?

---

Where `[p]`, from `console.log(angular.element(this));` above, looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For this I would recomment ui-bootstrap it handles tooltips very easily:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

But if you don't want to use it you can use something like this on table element.

in HTML:

```
<table ng-mouseover="getInfo($event)">
```

and in JS use:

```
     $scope.getInfo= function(event) {
      $scope.currentPosition = `${event.srcElement.offsetTop}/${event.srcElement.offsetLeft}`;
      console.log(event);
     }
```

Then you will have access to `event` in your function. `event` will contain `srcElement` which is element you've hovered. 
In example I'm getting `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` but you might use something else.

here's example:

https://jsfiddle.net/ng1mn8qp/5/

Comment: @Hi, I want the position of the `table row (tr)`, not `table data (td)`. Doing `angular.element($event.target);` or what you recommended `$event.srcElement` gets me the hovered `td` coordinates. So, I tried `angular.element($event.currentTarget);`, which gets me the parent `tr` element, but for some reason the coordinates are wrong, i.e., if the `td` in the parent `tr` is at `left: 82` and `top: 906`, the `tr` is at `0` and `36`? Why is this?

Comment: Well isn't top position of the td same as top position of tr? So if offsetTop gives you top offset for td it should be the same as tr, so I don't understand your concern here. You have everything you need in console check that event that I log in my example - if you're still concerned you can use event.srcElement.parentElement.offsetTop and event.srcElement.parentElement.offsetLeft .

Comment: I don't have the `left` position of the `tr` though, right? Unless I a) rely on them hovering over the first `td` and using that, or b) getting the first `td` from the array of `td`s in `tr`. I was more so trying to rely on getting the coordinates of the element of concern, not piecing together things.

Comment: @Also, If I check the `tr` element in console (`angular.element(event.currentTarget);`), It shows the `tr` at `(0, 36)` which I find odd as it's completely off from its children `td` coordinates (Same results as `event.srcElement.parentElement.offsetTop` and `event.srcElement.parentElement.offsetLeft`)

Comment: You're not checking things I'm writing, you are stuck with event.currentTarget which will get you table element since you have ng-mousemove on that element. You need event.srcElement (read about event propagation - https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/) Just check my previous comment and if you can't work it out I will make you example on fiddle tomorrow. You might be interested in this as well which will get you position and width/height of tr element: event.srcElement.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect()

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `track by` attribute to your ng-repeat. Something like `ng-repeat="s in sessions track by $index"`, the `$index` variable is the current index, so you can use it to search through your table rows and get the correct one.

Comment: I'm already tracking by index. How do I "search through table rows"? Doesn't passing `this` through on `ng-mouseover` solve that? Or at least should?

Comment: it should indeed, try adding your code that shows the popup in a `$timeout(function(){});` it usualy solve many problems.